# Why BigtableIO writes records one by one after GroupBy/Combine DoFn?

Tags: bigtable, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Is someone aware of how the bundles are working within BigtableIO? Everything looks fine until one is using `GroupBy` or `Combine` DoFn. At this point, the pipeline would change the pane of our `PCollection` element from `PaneInfo.NO_FIRING` to `PaneInfo{isFirst=true, isLast=true, timing=ON_TIME, index=0, onTimeIndex=0}` and then `BigtableIO` will output the following log `INFO  o.a.b.sdk.io.gcp.bigtable.BigtableIO - Wrote 1 records`. Is the logging causing a performance issue when one have millions records to output or is it the fact that `BigtableIO` is opening and closing a writer for each record?

Answer (score 1):

BigtableIO sends multiple records in a batch RPC.  However, that assumes there there are multiple records sent in the "bundle".  Bundle sizes are dependent on a combination of the step before hand, and the Dataflow framework.  The problems you're seeing don't seem to be related to `BigtableIO` directly.

FWIW, [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.0.0/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigtable/BigtableIO.java#L592)'s the code for logging the number of records that occurs in the `finishBundle()` method.

Comment: I understood that as well, but I'm wondering why it's making bundle of only 1 record. Wouldn't be a trick to set the minimum bundle size? I tried to apply another Window and to trigger only when a certain amount of data arrived in the Window, but I still have one record per bundle...